# Is there a way to reset values and formulas of a spreadsheet everytime it opens?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a calculator/simulator and would like many users to use it. As you can imagine, for a simulation to work there are many formulas underneath the values, but I also want to give the users the ability to overwrite some of the formulas in case they have better information that my projections.

So, as not to break this calculator/simulator, I need to reset or restore (not sure what the right word is) my values/formulas when each user closes the tab containing the spreadsheet, so the next user has a clean slate to start from and all formulas and values are reset to what I originally built.

I have found out how to clear out cells and delete values when opening the file, but I have not been able to like copy all the information when it opens, save it, and then paste it on top of any changes when it opens again.
I have just found a way to cell by cell and formula by formula, set the values as I want them onOpen, but as you can imagine, this way takes time and is very high maintenance.

I have also tried this code but it pastes all values as a string and not in their respective cells

```
function onOpen() {
var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = file.getSheetByName('What_If')
var modelData = sheet.getRange('B2:R44').getValues()
var modelData2 = sheet.getRange('B2:R44');
modelData2.setValues(modelData);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. I have read your question but I cannot understand EXACTLY what is your problem. Would you please explain in more detail and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy values and formulas from template with onOpen trigger...
First, create template spreadsheet with all values and formulas that need to be copied.
Then, copy this code to your editor (in spreadsheet that will be exposed to users)

```
function resetOnOpen() {
  const file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const file2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("INSERT_HERE_ID_OF_TEMPLATE_DOCUMENT");
  const sheet = file.getSheetByName('What_If')
  const sheet2 = file2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const range = sheet.getRange('B2:R44');
  const range2 = sheet2.getRange('B2:R44');
  const numRows = range2.getNumRows();
  const numCols = range2.getNumColumns();

  var dataFromTemplate = range2.getValues();
  range.setValues(dataFromTemplate);
  
  var formulas = sheet2.getRange('B2:R44').getFormulas();

  for (let i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
      var cellValue = formulas[j][i];
      if (cellValue != ""){
          range.getCell(j+1,i+1).setFormula(cellValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, go to Triggers (in Editor),
choose AddTrigger,
Choose which function to run -- resetOnOpen,
Select event source -- From spreadsheet,
Select event type -- onOpen,
and finally Save.
Now just reload your spreadsheet that will be exposed to users... Good luck!